# Why Firestore returns a Collection Reference but my program treat its as an Array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

So I made a simple app on Vue. Then I realized it would be cool to connect it with an online database so I thought I would try Firebase (i have very little backend knowledge so i wanted something fast and "simple").

The problem is in the next line:

```js
firestore () {
      return {
        items: db.collection('items')
      }
    }
```

When i do that, my original array `items` which is located in the usual `data()` of any vue component, gets filled with the objects of that collection.

The problem is I only want to get the field of each object in that collection (for example, the field `name` of each to-do item), not the entire object. I looked and it seems there´s no easy way as doing "db.collection('items).name"

So i thought in doing a function to get that data into an array and then pass it in items:

```js
function cleanRawData(objectToClean){
      var cleanedArr = [];

      for(let i=0; i<objectToClean.length; i++){
        cleanedArr.push(objectToClean[i].name)
      }

      return cleanedArr
}

 data () {
      return {
          
          items: [],

        }
    },
    firestore () {
      let itemObject = db.collection('items');
      return {
       items: cleanRawData(itemObject)
      }
    }
```

Well I dont know if If i´ve made a lot of mistakes there but the point is i want to "clean" what Firestore gives me.

The problem is i can´t even try the function because when i `console.log(db.collection('items'))` doesn´t give me an array of objects but a "Firestore Collection" however why then the App renders perfectly the data like if it´s being a simple array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/) and in particular the [declarative binding](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/).

This is why by simply doing

```
  firestore: {
    items: db.collection('items')
  }
```

you populate the `items` array (and this array is updated anytime there is a change in the collection).

---

So, depending on what you exactly want to do you may use one of the two approaches presented below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="i in items">{{ i.name }}</li>
    </ol>

    <ol>
      <li v-for="n in names">{{ n }}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "../firebase";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    };
  },

  firestore: {
    items: db.collection('items')
  },
  computed: {
    names() {
      return this.items.map(item => {
        return item.name;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If you just want to display the name of each `item` you can use the approach in the first `v-for`, where, for each `item`, we display the `name` property of the `item`.

If you really want to generate another array with only the names, use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). Note that the second `v-for` shows the same result when looping over the `names` (computed) array.